# Uploading item to API from UWP - Setting a folder to auto-upload

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

So i'm trying to upload a file through a UWP app, but everything i search for (every question answered on SO for example) shows the back-end code for it.

What kind of INPUT control could i use to browse the items ?

This is what i want to achieve ->

Select items, send them to the back-end UWP to generate a SHA1 for them and then do some api calls. One with the SHA1 that receives a link and another call to that link to upload the item. To be more exact i want to upload files to the OpenLoad API (thats how it works).

Also, is there any way i could specify a folder in my app settings and send all the files in there for upload ? (Instead of doing the above with an input like "upload files").
Something like google drive, but instead of auto-uploading files placed there (since i'd need to check if they were already uploaded) i'd do it on a button press. I might be able to check if the items are already on the server, but i'm not sure yet.

My experience is in web development so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked the [Open files and folders with a picker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-using-file-and-folder-pickers) document?

Comment: I think i might';ve stumbled upon it while searching for a way to upload, but i can't really understand it. Shouldnt the code in a UWP app have BOTH a front-end XAML and a back-end C# (back-end not 100% necesary)? Where would i place such a code and how would i arrange it in my view?

Comment: The files and folders picker is UWP storage APIs. It's not a XAML control. In your case, you could put a button on the XAML page, and put the `Open files and folders with a picker` code in its event handler.

Comment: Ah, now i understand. Haven't had the time to test it yet, but many thanks!